# Problem 2.7.5 on page 35 Ayman Badawi's solution manual.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, ring-theory

[image]

Something in this argument of the proof of this claim seems lacking.
Shouldn't it be $y=w=ad$ in the notation in the book?

I mean he wants to show that if $y\in \Phi^{-1}(K)$ then $y\in Ker(\Phi)D$.
Appreciate your input.

Comment: Please don't rely on pictures of text.

Comment: You seem to ignore that pictures should not be used. But read [this post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question), why.

Comment: @shaun why pictures shouldn't be used? it's easier to crop and save and then upload it than typing the passage from the book.

Comment: Why not? Again, read [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question). So think about *what exactly* you want to type for the question. This improves your question a lot. It forces you to think about the essential part, and often people have an insight this way themselves.

Comment: Of course it is easier just to upload homework or whatever without effort. But exactly this is often not well received at this forum.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that his proof of $\ker(\phi)D\subset\phi^{-1}(K)$ works fine, but the other inclusion is where his proof seems to not make sense since he says that $y\in \phi^{-1}(K)\subset G$, and then he says that this implies that $y=\phi(w)$ for some $w\in G$, but this does not make sense since $y\in G$, and $\phi(w)\in H$.

Here is my proof of the inclusion $\phi^{-1}(K)\subset \ker(\phi)D$. So let $y\in \phi^{-1}(K)$, our goal is to show that $y=zd$ where $z\in\ker(\phi)$ and $d\in D$. Since $y\in\phi^{-1}(K)$, this implies that $\phi(y)\in K$. Now we are told that $D$ is a subgroup of $G$ such that $\phi(D)=K$, so there is some $d\in D$ such that $\phi(d)=\phi(y)\in K$. Thus, we will have that $\phi(y)\phi(d)^{-1}=e_H$. Thus, we have that $\phi(yd^{-1})=e_H$ or $yd^{-1}\in\ker(\phi)$. Now let us denote $z:=yd^{-1}$. Then we observe that $y=zd$ where $z\in \ker(\phi)$ and $d\in D$ which is precisely what we wanted to show.

Comment: Simple and elegant. Thanks!